# Enzyme doesn't reflect the setState changes inside an asynchronous setState callback

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I've trying to figure this out for a whole day and I can't get it to work.

I have a component that updates the state inside `componentDidMount`, and then in the `setState's` callback I am updating the state again but the callback runs asynchronously. This is because I make an http request in there whose response I use to update the state. During unit-testing I mock this module so it doesn't reach the network. But Enzyme doesn't reflect the state changes in the async callback. Which makes sense because it's asynchronous, but I haven't found any work around for this.

I've built a minified version of what I'm trying to achieve.

This is my component:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 0,
        };
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        this.setState(state => {
            const { value } = this.state;
            return {
                ...state,
                value: value + 15,
            };
        }, async () => {
            try {
                // If you remove this line, it works. 
                await Promise.resolve(15);
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState(state => {
                        const { value } = this.state;
                        // If you console.log during testing,
                        // this value is updated correctly, but Enzyme doesn't reflect it.
                        return {
                            ...state,
                            value: value + 15,
                        };
                    });
                }
            } catch(e) {
                // Do nothing...
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    render() {
        const { value } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>{ value } </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is my test:

```js
describe('Component Enzyme Bug Testing', () => {
    it('should update value properly', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Component />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
        wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
        expect(wrapper.state().value).toEqual(30);
    });
});
```

In the test run, `state().value` is 15, when the expected is 30. Which mean that it registered the first change, but not the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When IO-bound code is executed in Node, the callbacks for those operations are not run in the current context, they are placed back onto the event loop ([more info](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)) and then executed on the next "tick". What this effectively means is, when you run synchronous code that calls asynchronous code, even if the asynchronous code isnt *actually* asynchronous (e.g. `Promise.resolve`), it will still run *after* the synchronous code has ran to completion.

In your case, as you mentioned in your code comments, the test only begins to fail when you introduce `Promise.resolve` and that's because at this point we shift the state change to a different context and then the test runs to completion and the assertion fails (as you would hopefully now understand why).

To fix the test, it's fairly simple, knowing that the state update is now going to run on the next tick, we simply want to schedule our assertion to do the same:

```
it('should update value properly', done => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
  wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
  process.nextTick(() => {
    expect(wrapper.state().value).toEqual(30);
    done();
  })
});
```

This places the assertion to run on the same tick as the state update and, as per the article, we know the event loop phases follow a FIFO model therefore we can guarantee the assertion will run after the state update.

Comment: Woah, I did not know any of that. Thank you so much! :)